# Can you split a variable into multiple variables?

Tags: powershell, variables

Is it possible to split a variable into two separate variables and how would I go about it. For example, taking this string:

```
$name = "firstname.surname"
```

and spitting it into:

```
$firstname 
$surname
```

Comment: I'm sure you meant to put quote marks around "firstname.surname" in your example?

Answer (score 3):

### Using `split`

1. Using the `.split` *method*. Note that the result of a `split` is an array, and you have to choose which item (aka index) in the array you want to assign to the new variables:

   ```
   $firstname = $name.split(".")[0]
   $surname   = $name.split(".")[1]
   ```
2. Using the `-split` *operator*. Note that in the examples below the dot "." needs to be escaped with a preceeding "\", else it will be interpreted as a Regex meaning "any character":

   ```
   $firstname = ($name -split("\."))[0]
   $surname   = ($name -split("\."))[1]
   ```
3. Or if you are sure you will split into an array of two items:

   ```
   $firstname,$surname = $name -split("\.")
   ```

Read more:

- [about_Split](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

### Using Regex

You could split the string "firstname.surname" with a regex. This example uses named regex groups called 'text1' and 'text2' which together match any string that has (at least) two bits of text with a dot in between.

```
$name = "firstname.surname"

if($name -match '(?<text1>[^.]+)\.(?<text2>[^.]+)'){
  $firstname = $matches['text1']
  $surname   = $matches['text2']
}
```